# Human Resources Management-Salary deduction

Tags: salary

I am going to deduct salary of an absent employee. he is absent for 2 days and his monthly salary is 2500 US dollars. our working days are 22 and the month has 31 days at all.
what should i do in bellow to options?

2500/31*2 or 2500/22*2

basis on working days (22 days) or whole month (31 days)

Comment: Don't you have regulations/rules for that? Can *you* just decide on your own how to do that? What country are you in - there's probably laws for what you can and can't do.

Comment: I am looking for standard rules?

Comment: This question appears to be an outright off-topic because it is **[about](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour)** deducting a salary

Comment: @Rahmatullah The standard rules depend on the applicable laws, and these depend on your location.

Comment: If you don't know you may not be the right person to make that decision anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You should first wait for the employee to come back and see what happened. For all you know that absent employee might be in a hospital unable to communicate with anyone. So there might be a situation where you need to pay the full salary, and deducting anything might get you into trouble.

If the reason is such that you shouldn't pay, you might consider alternatives like deducting the absent days from the employee's holiday. Which might be the better solution anyway, because that way your company doesn't lose two days of work.

If you take it as unpaid leave (and employees might be able to take unpaid leave anyway if there is a good reason), you shouldn't base this on a month because months have different lengths, you should base it on the expected days per year that an employee works. You wouldn't deduct different amounts in February (28 days) and March (29 days).

When you think about 22 vs 31 days: Imagine the employee is absent the whole month. 22 working days absent. How much would you pay according to each method, and how much would you want to pay?

Comment: We have come to the end from all possible ways you have mentioned. now it is time to deduct hi salary. Just, i need what to do regarding it. salary/31*2 or salary/22*2?

Answer (score 2):

That is actually a question for the finance department in your organization, and the actual salary should be calculated at the end of the month once the employee is back in the office and circumstances have been clarified (as @gnasher points out, there are several, possibly better alternatives to pay deduction). Still the basic answer to your question should be simple.

Employees are paid based on the number of their effective working days, not per calendar day. (In fact, if your employee were paid per calendar day, you had no right to deduce pay as the number of days in the month doesn't change regardless of absences ;-)

So for a month with 22 working days, your employee's daily pay is 2500 / 22.

Comment: That is not exactly true, and depends a lot on how your local laws regulate work. On Brazil, for example, Sundays are considered "Paid Rest" and Saturdays are "Half-days", so for a 4-week month you have actually 28 work days. Not showing up on a saturday is different business that not showing up on a Monday. Overtime done on a Sunday counts as Double Hours, and the list of differences goes on... this is really dependent of the country in question.

Comment: @ThalesPereira, I based my calculation on data from the OP. Yes, the number of working days, days off, overtime etc. are calculated differently in different countries, however IMO all this is out of scope here. I believe that 2 days absence is 2 days absence whether it was on 2 normal weekdays in India or 4 Saturdays in Brazil.

Answer (score 1):

When I was hired by my current employer (a publicly traded company), I started work on a Tuesday. I'm non-exempt so they needed to pay me a partial week. They used the following:

**(Annual / hours per year) * (hours per day * days)**

So if I were making a round figure like 100k, it would have been:

**(100,000 / 2080) * (8 * 4)**

or

**1,538.46**

*parentheses are merely for clarity*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another method. Say a person gets $2500 per month. That's for the 31-day months, and for our 28-day Februari.

The other answers are dependant on the monthlength (I disregard working/free days in the example below):
- 31 day month 2 days less will mean: 2/31 * $2500 = $161
- 28 day month 2 days less will mean: 2/28 * $2500 = $179

IMO the month should not matter. 2 days is 2 days. If the monthly salary isn't dependend on monthlength, so shouldn't sick-days.

**My solution:**
Base it on the amount of working days in the whole year (averaging all the month together). Again, not taking free days into account (principle is the same though):

2 days out of 356, multiplied by amount of months (12) times monthly salary:
- ( 2/365 ) / ( 12*2500 ) = $164

Bonus for this method is that it doesnt matter if a month has 4 or 5 weekends in it. It's not (very) dependend on calenderdates. This method is a lot more transparant to understand.